# How to create a Back button which will land at the specific text/link clicked on to view an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do: 
I have mutiple anchor links within text, each of which refers to and connects to a specific image (on the same page).

After the user views that image, I would like them to hit a 'Back' button, which will bring them back to the text where they clicked on the link, to continue reading from where they left off. 
(I have created the button in the html, with an 'id' of 'backButton').

Note: I am new to JS and jQuery, and perhaps my inability to find a plugin or explanation of how to do this has something to do with a failure to do a search with a clear and concise explanation in a search box.
(It seems to me that this would be a fairly commonly used feature)

This is where I currently stand with my attempts to use jquery for this:

```
$(function(){

    $('a').click(function(){

        $(this).attr('id', 'backToLink').addClass('que');

        $('#backButton').attr('href', '#backToLink');   
    });
});
```

(I will try to explain my reason for why I did each step so that someone might tell me why it is wrong):

```
$('a').click(function(){
```

For each anchor, when it is clicked on, do this function,

`$(this)`
Refer to the anchor link that was clicked,

`.attr('id', 'backLink')`
Give this anchor the 'id' of `backToLink`,

`.addClass('que');`
Add the `class` of `que`, which is set in my CSS file to give `padding-top` so that the text will be visible below the `fixed-position` `header`,

`$('#backButton').attr('href', '#backToLink');`
Set the `#backButton` `href` to go back to the original link in the text, which should now be `#backToLink`.

Note: I suspect it will be necessary to `turn off` that `id` of `#backToLink` after it is used,
so that the next time it is used it will not conflict with the first.

Comment: How does user view an image? Are they redirected to a different page, or does a new window open, or does a popup appear on the same page?

Comment: The image is on the same page. When the link is clicked on, there is a 'smooth scroll' effect which brings them to that image.

Comment: I am not proposing it as an answer, but some idea in different direction - create button when image is in focus: $('img').focus(function(){
        $(this).append('<a href="#backToLink"><button id="mtBtn">Back</button></a>');
        $('#myBtn').addClass('que');
 $('#myBtn').click(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('id', 'myBtn');
  });
 });

Comment: Does each image have a unique Id? Also, if you could post the structure of your DOM it would be helpful.

Comment: Call a function when you click on your link to store the scrollTop position of it and the code in the back button should scroll to that value. It will fail to work correctly if the window is resized. I recommend you to open the image in a floating div...

Comment: Oleg Markoff  I'm not sure if that fits with what I am trying to do design-wise, but I will play with it to see what I can learn.
The last part for 'removeAttr' will be very helpful, so it won't interfere with the next time it is used.
Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Nick G  Each image has a unique id. As I am new to this, I have to ask what you are looking for in regard to the 'structure of the DOM'? Thank you.

Comment: DIEGO CARRASCAL  I like the idea of determining the scroll position of the anchor link. and using that number as the target.  
I am a little reluctant partly because many of the images are in pairs, and I am not yet sure how floating divs will affect that positioning. 
It will take me some time to experiment with all of this. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is if you want to use anchor navigation then you dont need to use html button. Just simply use anchors. Here is a simple example of what you want to achieve. You can add in logic to make it dynamic according to your needs or keep it like this with adding the number of links manually. Hope this helps.

P.S. css classes are used just to add spacing to demonstrate the scrolling.

```js
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("a").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor($(this).attr('href').slice(1));
});
```

```css
#container{
  height:2800px;
}
#block1{
  background-color:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:1000px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#block2{
  background-color:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:600px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#lk1" name="bk1">Link to Block 1</a>
  <br><br>
  <a href="#lk2" name="bk2">Link to Block 2</a>
  <br>
  <div id="block1"></div>
  <a href="#bk1" name="lk1">Back to Link 1</a>
  <br>
  <div id="block2"></div>
  <a href="#bk2" name="lk2">Back to Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: UPDATE: 
I currently have the 'backButton' taking me back to the text/link that brought me to the image, as I wanted:
$('a').click(function(){
   
   $(this).attr('id', 'BackToLink').attr('class', 'que');
    
  });
(I have given the 'backButton anchor' href="#BackToLink").

I now need to figure out how/ where/ when to remove the 'id' of 'backToLink' from one anchor link, so that I can then apply it to the next one that is clicked on. ( It currently just takes me back to the first one).

Maybe: 
$('a').removeAttr('id', 'BackToLink');
but I can't find the right place to use it.